# Issue in accessing tomcat7 console over SSL

Tags: java, firefox, ssl, tomcat7

I have enabled SSL on tomcat 7 for server side authentication.
For this I have generated self signed certificate with keytool using following
set of commands :

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias temp -keystore temp.jks -storepass passwd
```

I have done the following changes in server.xml.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"    
    SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreType="JKS"
    keystoreFile="[PATH TO KEYSTORE]"
    keystorePass="passwd" keyAlias="temp"/>
```

After starting the tomcat, When I am trying the access the tomcat on https using following URL: localhost:8443, 
the expected popup comes in firefox asking whether to trust the self signed certificate(That means there is not any problem 
with server.xml configuration because Tomcat is able to locate the certificate successfully)
, whether to add the 
security exception. I allowed to add the security exception.But when next time When I am trying to access
the above url, Mozilla is showing the following error message:

Secure Connection Failed

```
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8443. 
Peer reports it experienced an internal error. (Error code:    
ssl_error_internal_error_alert)
```

Can somebody tell me, how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can view the tomcat logs and see if there are any errors. By default the logs are saved in the (tomcat install folder)/logs/catalina.out

Comment: I checked the tomcat logs inside folder location .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs. Found following log entry 
   "127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2014:16:54:27 +0530] "GET /SamlDemo/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -"

Comment: That seems like an entry from the "local_access_log" file, the errors are logged in the "catalina.out" file, which should be in the same folder. "catalina.out" is a text file, you can open it with notepad.

Comment: "cataline.out" is not present there.Only access_log files are present there.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of google-fu:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/750946

Check to see if your server is using Oracle's JDK or if it is using OpenJDK.

BTW, you'll want to use Oracle's JDK.  OpenJDK is not good for certificates and causes a lot of headaches.  As you've most likely learned.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7 with JDK 1.7. I have latest version of Mozilla on my machine(Firefox 33.0). I did some investigation and I guess there is some problem in TLS versions compatibility at both the sides.
        Tomcat 7 does not support SSLV3 & TLS 1.0 only supports TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.2
        On the other hand Firefox does not support TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.2 yet. I thinks this is causing the problem. I am thinking in this direction to solve the problem.

Comment: I know that Firefox is changing the algorithms that they accept, but I'm not totally clear on what is really going on with that change.  So, I've kept quiet, but I think reviewing the algorithms is a great idea.  You might consider upping the keysize argument when you create your key:  keytool -genkey -alias <alias> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore <keystore_name>.jks

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of suggestions at this point.  Best of luck.  Please try to keep this question up to date if you find the solution.  I'm sure others will run into this problem in the future.